# Compile external native library

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm triying to compile a native external library called Eigen (which consist in .h files) to use it in my App project. To do so, I've tried to configure my CMakeList.txt file using this guide [Configure CMake](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake.html).  I've been reading a lot of blogs and forums, but since I'm pretty new on Android NDK I don't understand these things:

1. **Do I need a file called Android.mk to add this library to my project?**
   Because I red a lot of this file, but it don't exist in my Project Structure
2. **What are the changes that I have to do in CMakeLists.txt?**
   I've tried adding that:

   `//Sets lib_src_DIR to the path of the target CMake project.`
   `set( Eigen_src_DIR ../Eigen )`
   `//Sets lib_build_DIR to the path of the desired output directory.`
   `set( lib_build_DIR ../Eigen/output)` 
   `file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${lib_build_DIR})`

   `//Adds the CMakeLists.txt file located in the specified directory`
   `// as a build dependency.`
   `add_subdirectory( # Specifies the directory of the CMakeLists.txt file.`
                 `${lib_src_DIR}`
                 `# Specifies the directory for the build outputs.`
                 `${lib_build_DIR})`

   `// Adds the output of the additional CMake build as a prebuilt static library and names it lib_gmath.`
   `add_library( lib_eigen STATIC IMPORTED )`
   `set_target_properties( lib_eigen PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION`
                      `${lib_build_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib_eigen.a )`
   `include_directories( ${lib_src_DIR}/Eigen )`

I've placed the folder with this library in `../app/Eigen`

Comment: This question is unclear, you say that you can both compile and not compile  C++ code.

Comment: Yes sorry. I have cpp files that work fine (I suppose they are compiled in the device in runtime when i launch the project) but i can't add an external library called Eigen because (if a i'm right) I need to do some changes in Android.mk file to give the path of this library to the compiler. And my problem is that this file don't exist in my project structure

Comment: _"bothers me because I need them to do what I want"_ What do you want to do? I mean this is a Q&A forum so tell us what you want to do and what you tried so far and we will help you to solve your problem...

Comment: I've edit the question, I hope it is clearer. Thank you